# How can I call click wrapped function as normal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have a command as:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1)
def test(count):
    click.echo('Count: %d' % count)
```

How can I call this `test(...)` as normal Python function?

I tried to call the function as `test("123")`, but received exception:

> Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (1 2 3)

So, assuming that the `test(...)` function comes with a *third-party package* and I can't modify anything in the function, how can I call this `test(...)` function?

Answer (score 3):

Click calls this out as an antipattern, and recommends you do things like:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1)
def test(count):
    result = _test(count)
    click.echo(result)

def _test(count):
    return f"Count: {count}"
```

Structuring your code in this way draws a clear separation between your API and your business logic, which is typically useful.

Comment: make sense. Unfortunately, I want to call a click wrapped function from a third-party package.

Comment: you can perhaps do `context.invoke` to ask `click` to make the call for you?

Comment: Would you mind adding an example for me?